# pandasのデータフレームで縦持ち横持ちの変換をしたい

Tags: python3, pandas

下記のようなpandas.DataFrameがある時に、縦持ちに変換を行いたいです。
調べたところpivot_tableが使用できそうな感じはありますが、うまく使用する事ができませんでした。

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 'e1', 'e11'], [1, 'e1', 'e22'], [2, 'e1', 'e33']], columns=['id', 'c1', 'c2'])
df1

# id c1 c2
# 0 e1 e11
# 1 e1 e22
# 2 e1 e33
```

変換後

```
# id c_name value
# 0 c1 e1
# 0 c2 e11
# 1 c1 e1
# 1 c2 e22
# 2 c1 e1
# 2 c2 e33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

すいません。自己解決できました。

```
pd.melt(df1,id_vars=['id'], value_vars=['c1', 'c2'])
```

---

```
id variable value
0 c1 e1
1 c1 e1
2 c1 e1
0 c2 e11
1 c2 e22
2 c2 e33
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['e1', 'e11'], ['e1', 'e22'], ['e1', 'e33']], columns=['c1','c2'])


df1.stack()
0  c1     e1
   c2    e11
1  c1     e1
   c2    e22
2  c1     e1
   c2    e33
dtype: object
```

こっちのほうがスマート？